# A cookie not in document.cookie list while http_only = false

Tags: javascript, cookies, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum, x-xsrf-token

I have a Nuxt.js frontend application, which performs an authentication request. There is a Laravel/Sanctum application on the backend. It uses built-in cookie-based session authentication. The authentication request fails because **no** X-XSRF-TOKEN HTTP header is provided in the /login request. Can anybody help to clarify why the header is not created from the cookie provided by the backend?

Note: Everything works properly on my laptop. It fails only when deployed to test enveronment (GCP VM instance + Gitlab Pages).

Auth code in Nuxt.js:

```
this.$axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; await
this.$axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
console.log(document.cookie);
await this.$axios.post("/login", credentials);
```

[I can see that XSRF-TOKEN cookie is returned by server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmk9L.png)

[I also see that the XSRF-TOKEN cookie is provided in the /login POST request, while no X-XSRF-TOKEN HTTP header is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enV5z.png)

[Cookie details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XdBN.png)

I also debuged the axios source code and see the it tries to create X-XSRF-TOKEN header taking the XSRF token from the document.cookie. But document.cookie doesn't contain the token cookie as of that moment. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. The session domain was incorrect. I have set .my-domain.co.uk and it works now.